# How can I put the values of an object's property into an array?

Tags: javascript

```
{
    "tin": "TIN is required",
    "bic": "BIC is required",
}
```

I need to put all the property values of an object into an array.

```
{
    "tin": ["TIN is required"],
    "bic": ["BIC is required"],
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.entries()` gives you an array of key value pairs

```js
const obj = {
    "tin": "TIN is required",
    "bic": "BIC is required",
}

console.log(Object.entries(obj))
```

---

Update due to comment:

```js
const obj = {
    "tin": "TIN is required",
    "bic": "BIC is required",
}

for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  obj[k] = [v];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I was wrong in my question. I need to put only the property values into the array, not the entire property. 

{
    "tin": ["TIN is required"],
    "bic": ["BIC is required"],
}

Comment: @Alex Sure, updated

Answer (score 1):

If u don't care much about performance
just use `Object.entries` and `Array.reduce`.

```js
const res = Object.entries(yourObj).reduce((acc, [k,v]) => {
  acc[k] = [v]; return acc;
}, {})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `Object.keys(yourobject)`:

```js
console.log(Object.keys({
    "tin": "TIN is required",
    "bic": "BIC is required",
}));
```